# Made silly changes to eclipse project and need to know if I can roll back to old build path or settings

Tags: eclipse

Not sure this is possible but if I have made changes to eclipse by mistake, can I roll back to a previous time with eclipse where I did not make those changes.

I changed build paths by mistake and selected right click use as source which also screwed some things up.  Is there anyway to fix this?

Comment: Was it under source control, e.g. git?

Comment: it was but that would not help with eclipse I had to start over import everything again...